# vlc embedded php playlist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, vlc

I want to create php playlist for VLC player which is embedded on web page. I want when I click on button to change the song or movie, without refreshing the page.
I want all movies and songs to be inside in the php file because the url path of songs and movies will be retrieve directly from mysql base. Also is very important the channel list to be not visible for everyone. In javascript all songs url paths links are visible.

Also if possible to encrypt the target name of the VLC, if the real link is http://xxx.xx.org/test/lista/u2-one.avi to be encrypted in http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xx.org%2Ftest%2Flista%2Fu2-one.avi

example

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
width="300"
height="300"
name="tv"
target="<?php echo $movie ?>"
id="tv">
```

php playlist

```
<?php
 $movie = 'http://xxx.xx.org/test/lista/u2-one.avi';
 $mp3='http://xxx.xx.org/test/lista/coldplay-yellow.mp3';
 $coldplay='http://xxx.xx.org/test/lista/coldplay-paradise.mp3';
?>
```

example

```
<button onclick="vlc.playlist.playItem(0); ">Coldplay</button>
```

[Here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/) is pretty much explained , but I don't have experience in javascript.

Comment: Hmm, you should nail down your question to little problems we can solve with code examples. What you are asking is to write a whole application..

Answer (score 0):

Your playlist contains only `$movie`. You need to fill playlist `vlc.playlist.add(mrl,name,options)` then you can use `vlc.playlist.playItem(number)`

JS:

```
var options = new Array();
var id1 = vlc.playlist.add('http://xxx.xx.org/test/lista/u2-one.avi', "Movie", options);
var id2 = vlc.playlist.add('http://xxx.xx.org/test/lista/coldplay-yellow.mp3', "Mp3", options);
var id3 = vlc.playlist.add('http://xxx.xx.org/test/lista/coldplay-paradise.mp3', "Coldplay", options);
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="vlc.playlist.playItem(id3);">Coldplay</button>
```

Comment: I have very strange problem, I have several songs added to the playlist, when I listen one of the songs , the song doesn't plays to the end, the vlc player automatically skip to the next song . Is it bug or there is something wrong with my javascript code ?

Example: The duration of Marc Anthony's song is 5:25, the player plays the song until 4:00, then suddenly change song to next playlist item in this case U2-One.